# Azure function with .net core 2 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

Since there is still no support for Webjobs in ASP.Net Core, i am going to use Azure functions instead.

I have 2 class libraries that are build with on .net core 2. i can reference them to my Azure function project without any issue but when i try to publish i get this error.

[image: Error]

This is the reference from the Azure function to my lib
[image]

Any idea on how i can make this work? without changing my class lib?

Comment: Functions run on top of Web Jobs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Functions doesn't currently support .Net Core 2 (more specifically, .Net Standard 2), however, it seems like the team is actively working on getting this support out...see here: [Port runtime to .NET Core](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/98)

> Runtime will be ported to target Netstandard 2.0.

Depending on the functionality of your libraries, you may see if its possible to target instead Netstandard 1.3 which they do currently support

> This issue will track the .NET Core port activities for porting the runtime to .NET core. Note that netstandard 1.3 assemblies can be used on Azure Functions and this is fully supported.

Update: added clarity based on @derape comments

Comment: What can i do instead to create that type of functionality?

Answer (score 4):

.NET Core 2.0 is now supported by Azure Functions.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, i am testing it now and i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> Since there is still no support for Webjobs in ASP.Net Core

My understanding is that the VS tooling is not ready yet, so you cannot have a project template targeted at that, or some easy *Publish as webjobs* menu item.

But as far as I got reading through blog posts, you can create a .NET Core console application, add some `.cmd` file to project root with content like:

```cmd
REM run.cms - Webjob entry point
@echo off
dotnet MyNetCoreConsoleApplication.dll
```

include that in the set of published files (with *project.json* `"publishOptions": { "include": [...] }` and finally make the webjob point to that cmd script. See for example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/), or search for *azure webjobs dotnet core*.